# How to disable session cookie in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, session, cookies, session-cookies

In Google Chrome I can disable **cookies** as well as the **session cookies** by the following setting:

> Settings **>** Show Advanced Settings **>** Privacy **>** Content
>   Settings **>** Cookies **>** Block sites from setting any data

I am trying to achieve the same thing in IE (11) by -

> Internet Options > Privacy > Settings > Advanced > (check) Override
>   automatic cookie handling > Block both 1st and 3rd party cookies

This setting disables the cookies but not session cookies.
Is there any way how I can do this in IE ?

Answer (score 0):

To block or allow cookies based on type.

Rather than picking specific websites to block or allow, you can specify general types of cookies that are acceptable. For example, you can choose to allow cookies from websites that have privacy policies or to block those from websites that store personal information without your consent.

Open Internet Explorer by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button. In the search box, type Internet Explorer, and then, in the list of results, click Internet Explorer.

Click the **Tools button**, and then click **Internet options**.
Click the **Privacy** tab, move the **slider** to the level of privacy that you want to set, and then click OK.

As you move the slider, *Internet Explorer provides a description of the types of cookies that are blocked or allowed at that privacy level*.

*[Taken from this link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/how-to-manage-cookies-in-internet-explorer-9)

Comment: This is what I have already done. I have mentioned that in my question.